# Standalone Application with spark-java

Tags: javascript, java, spark-java

Is it possible to get a "standalone" application (I mean, a application which I code with java and the UI with swing oder swt) with spark and maybe some additional software, so that it seems to the user that he is using a "standalone" local application? So the UI can be used without a browser but with the benefits from spark.

Answer (score 1):

Off course. I use Sparjkava to provide backend to my rich client web apps, native Android, and why not a JavaFX or Swing desktop app. You would just have to develop your desktop app with the same behavior as a web app, I mean, it has to communicate with the server trough a Rest WebServer.